# What is the status of Omnitopia: East Wind by Diane Duane?

Tags: publishing

The sequel to Omnitopia: Dawn, released in 2010, *East Wind* is listed on Amazon as having a release date of August 2, 2011, but says "usually ships within 1 to 2 months" and no one seems to have received a copy. The e-book is listed as unavailable until 2025.

Little new information about the book can be found online; mostly what there is consists of uninformed speculation and people complaining that they haven't got a copy yet.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It occurs to me that this question might be considered inappropriate as it would become irrelevant as soon as the book comes out; I trust that in that case a moderator would remove it as quickly as possible.

Comment: I'm reopening this question. If the book does come out, we'll probably close it, but until then, it's a valid question.

Comment: Amazon sent me a "we cancelled your order because the item is not available" email.

Answer (score 2):

I did a review for this on Amazon's Kindle page for the book, because whoever is in charge of listing the release date set it incorrectly - it did not release on Aug 2 2011, and I seriously doubt 2025 is a serious release date for anything.

In August I read and gave a glowing review for the first book, *Omnitopia Dawn*, and was looking forward to reading this next book IMMEDIATELY AFTER -- I would NOT have bought book one if Amazon hadn't already listed book 2 as OUT *grrrrrs*.  It had listed the book available with 2 hard cover copies in stock.  FALSE INFO :( :( :(

So I wrote a complaint about how the *Omnitopia East Wind* book wasn't available despite misleading and incorrect info on Amazon's site.  This review was up on their page for a while, now it's gone and the review button is gone as well.  It's been months now and other than wiping out the review ability and any posted reviews, the info about an Aug 2 2011 release date for hard cover and Dec 2025 remains.  I find book listings like that irresponsible by the seller, they could at least just print that the publication date is on hold and more info will be released at a later date.